# Why does my python script break after compiling?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm checking out how much of a performance increase I get after compiling a python script. After research looking into this issue I don't think I will actually see an increase in performance with the script I have written because I found out that once the script is loaded, the execution time doesn't increase. I still would like to know why this is failing to run after compiling as this is my first time trying this. Here is my script

```
#!/bin/python3
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()

import psutil

BYTES_PER_GB = 1024*1024*1024

# Memory
m = psutil.virtual_memory()
#total = m.total/BYTES_PER_GB 
#available = m.available/BYTES_PER_GB
#used = m.used/BYTES_PER_GB
m_free= m.free/BYTES_PER_GB
m_percent = m.percent

# Swap
s = psutil.swap_memory()
s_free = s.free/BYTES_PER_GB
s_percent = s.percent

print(' %.1fG (%.1f%%)  %.1fG (%.1f%%)' % (m_free, m_percent, s_free, s_percent))
print(' %.1fG (%.1f%%)  %.1fG (%.1f%%)' % (m_free, m_percent, s_free, s_percent))

print(datetime.now() - start)
```

I'm trying to compile with this line

```
python3 -m py_compile memory
```

In my print statements I have some special characters from font awesome. Not sure if that would cause a problem but if it doesn't show up correctly in my post then that's what that is.

The output when I try to run the compiled file is

```
./memorycpython-35.pyc: line 1: $'\026\r\r': command not found
./memorycpython-35.pyc: line 2: �k�W��@s�ddlmZej�ZddlZdZej�Zejeej: command not found
./memorycpython-35.pyc: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./memorycpython-35.pyc: line 3: `ej
                                �Z
                                  e
e                                      je
 j  Ze�eej�e�dS)�)datetimeNiii@)rZnow�startZpsutilZ
                                                                   BYTES_PER_GBZvirtual_memory�mZfreeZm_freeZpercentZ   m_percentZ
              swap_memory�sZs_freeZ s_percent�print�rr�memory<module>s



       '
   ^[[?62;c^[[?62;c
```

***EDIT***

To narrow down the problem I wrote the following script

```
#!/bin/python3
print("Hello World!")
```

This is the output

```
./testcpython-35.pyc: line 1: $'\026\r\r': command not found
./testcpython-35.pyc: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./testcpython-35.pyc: line 2: `�r�W%�@sed�dS)z
                                               Hello World!N)�print�rr�./test<module>s'
```

Compiled using

```
python3 -m py_compile ./test
```

This creates a file in `__pycache__/` called `testcpython-35.pyc` which I then do `chmod +x testcpython-35.pyc` and `./testcpython-35.pyc`

Comment: Can you kindly change your font temporarily to get readable screen output, and paste an edit in your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. Are you referring to the 4 characters from font awesome?

Comment: Apologies, I think I get it now. You're saying that the output from python is actually garbled the way it is pasted in the last block in your post. Have you tried putting standard characters into your `print` statements to see if that fixes the problem? I suspect character encoding issues are a culprit here.

Comment: I have. I changed it to take out the two print statements with the font awesome characters. So the only two print statements I have are `print(m_free)` and `print(datetime.now() - start)`

Comment: @AndrewC. I added an edit with a simpler script. All it does it prints `Hello World!`

Comment: `./testcpython-35.pyc` - that's not how you run a `.pyc` file. Your system thinks it's a shell script.

Comment: @user2357112 That was the heart of my issue. I was thinking the shebang would still have an affect. When someone is new to something it's usually a small issue/misunderstanding that causes the issue. I hope this thread an help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears my issue is the `./testcpython-35.pyc` part. When I run `python3 testcpython-35.pyc`, independent on whether I did `chmod +x ./testcpython-35.pyc`, the output is scrabbled. As long as I run the compiled program by first specifying what program to run it with, `python3`, it outputs `Hello World!` as expected.